# How to creat Static cells with code instead of storyboard in UITabelViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview

In storyBoard,there are two type cells.One is Dynamic prototype.The other is static Cells.But when I want build a tableViewController without storyboard,How to creat static cells with code?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: you mean create static tableview with programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this this code.

It explain Create a static UITableView without Storyboards.

[Check the reference link](http://derpturkey.com/create-a-static-uitableview-without-storyboards/)

Comment: It is great. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just create it in your viewdidload

```
    UITableView *tblView =[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame style:UITableViewStylePlain]];
```

and in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

If you do this you dont need to configure it in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I search some similar questions.If we write a static UITableViewController with code. Maybe we don`t have to use UITableView. Instead we can use UIScrollview and some other UIControls.